# PHP Warning: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /some/path on line x

Tags: php, redis

Our application is running since years without any glitch and one day we decided to use redis as our caching server for speedy delivery of data. Redis was installed/configured on new server and content were cached basis business requirement. The redis services were used at application end. Post production deployment, page started throwing numerous
**warning:** *php_network_getaddresses*: *getaddrinfo* failed: Name or service not known in /path/of/the/calling/script/file

[image]

What would be the reason and resolution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development and testbed, we were using the different server, where I was able to make connection to redis server. But post production failover, I noticed, system was unable to resolve the address. It was unable to connect to caching.example.com

```
$redisServer = 'caching.example.com';
try {
    $redis = new Redis();
    $redis->connect($redisServer, 6379);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Doing the root cause analysis, I did the host entry for caching.example.com on production server and it worked.

Basically/Theoretically If you are trying to access a remote URL, then [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) is your best bet. You can provide a full URL to that function, and it will fetch the content at that location using a normal HTTP request.

If you only want to send an HTTP request and ignore the response, you could use [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) and manually send the HTTP request headers, ignoring any response. It might be easier with cURL though, or just plain old [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), which will open the connection but not necessarily read any response.